# Accessing .Text property in a Master Page from the Master.cs

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a textbox and a button, and I trying to give the user a search option in the master page.

The onClick event of my button is fine, but the textbox.Text property is always empty.

I googled a little and fine many articles about accessing the Master from the ContentHolder, but I believe its no my case...

Help appreciated :)

Pedro Dusso

Comment: Can you share some code for us to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it working.

Please check if there are any initialization of the TextBox.Text happening in 
Page.Onload() event.

Comment: For sure... I put a tbx.Text = string.Empty in the PageLoad to clean the textbox, and I forget the postback. Thanks man!